# What options are available for creating multiple cloud instances of a web-app for different customers

Tags: deployment

I have a web-app, that in production, will need to be sold to different companies. Th idea is to create a new instance of the application for each customer, for example:

Lets say that our app has a site at thing.com:

1. A company sing up for an instance of the application
2. The system receives this signup and (automatically?) creates a new instance of the web app at yourcompany.thing.com

I am wondering what options are available for the "system"? How can create multiple instances of that web-app when a company signs up?

An example of what I am looking to do can be seen when signing up for a [Youtrack](https://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/) in-cloud instance.

Comment: Am in a same situation right now. Have you found a solution yet? if you could share your solution it would be greatly appreciated.